# How to solve this integral that looks related to the Bessel function?

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.5020.pdf, they state the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vekz1.png) in equation 66.

My guess is that this perhaps follows from some Bessel function related identity, but I was not able to get the desired answer that way. I also tried to just integrate it out with Mathematica, starting from the integration over kz, which is still straightforward, but then when I went to the integral over kx I get a whole jungle of functions like the Bessel function and the Struve function so that I had no clue how to reproduce ths very simple result from the paper. Note that it has a  $\sim$ in front so perhaps there is a prefactor or a subleading term involved as well.

Comment: The integration in $k_z$ is logarithmically divergent if we assume an infinite space. How did you perform the integral over $k_z$? is there some volume in the system that the final result could depend on?

Comment: Oh wait sorry you're right, I accidentally got rid of the divergent part when performing the integral in mathematica, no indeed the integral over kz is divergent when integrated over over infinite space.